# Implementing GTM in multistore environment

Tags: magento-1.9, google-analytics, tags

Hi we are implementing Google Tag Manager (GTM) in our Magento store. We have a multistore environment /w 3 storenames & 2 views per stores (languages), making it 6 storeviews in total.

And that got me thinking during the GTM set-up process. **Question:** Does one set-up multiple accounts, or multiple containers (per storeview), or just 1 container to cover all stores? Using the multiple accounts and multiple containers method seemed like a lot of manual config.

fyi. we now started the 1 container solution. And created a macro lookup table per hostname returning for example the GUA ID. This way we have 1 rule that serves many storeviews.

How are other multistore owners running this?

Many thanks, Sean

[image]

Comment: Did you get an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookup table variable is the best approach for easy maintenance especially when you have loads of sites and planning to add more in future. Have a look at the below screenshot which will help you understand how lookup table variable works.

[image: Lookup table variable in GTM for multi-website setup]

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the amount of tags that are shared among all store views. GA is on all of them, but what other (online marketing) tags are used? Else you will need to be careful with your firing rules and always create lookup tables for IDs.